# Laravel Symbolic Link not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-filesystem

I have some problems creating a symbolic link with laravel to access files that are in my storage

I am storing my files in 
`storage\app\public`

I used the php artisan command to create the link
`php artisan storage: link
The [public/storage] directory has been linked.`

Earlier files were storing in `storage\app\public` and were also visible in `public\storage` folder

But now they are only storing in `storage\app\public` and not visible in `public\storage` folder

I am using link to show file path
`{{ Storage::url($package->reportPath['path']) }}`
Path is showing correct but it redirect to 404 page as there is no file I guess.

Comment: are you using `homestead`?

Comment: @SapneshNaik No, I am using Xampp

Answer (score 15):

This solved it for me on laravel 8, hosted on a ec2 server.

```
rm public/storage
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: This worked for me on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your public/storage directory and try running storage:link again. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to Show the stored file use asset()

```
asset('storage/further_path/').$file_name;
```

To store file you can do

```
$destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/further_path'); 
if (!is_dir($destinationPath)) {
    mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, TRUE); 
} 
$request->file->move($destinationPath,$filename);
```

Hope this Helps You.

Let me Know if You have any problem.

Comment: I need my symbolic link to work. Files are storing in `storage\app\public` but not visible in `public\storage`

Comment: symbolic link might be giving you system path which is not a url to view file hence returning you 404

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: instead of storage::url do asset

Comment: and where should I store my files?

Comment: store file 

$destinationPath = storage_path('app/public/further_path');
                if (!is_dir($destinationPath)) {
                    mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, TRUE);
                }
$file->move($path,$filename);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164595/discussion-between-rohit-shah-and-programmingarrow).